# Issue where Microsoft Graph API doesn't return any emails from a specific sender in an inbox

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, outlook-restapi

I am developing a microsoft office add-in and am running across some weird behavior when calling the api below.

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=from/emailaddress/address eq 'XXXXX@XXXX.com'

This is returning results for some people and giving me my email history with them but others it is getting zero when I have received and can see emails from them in my inbox.

I am using axios to make the call in the application and I have tried with the graph explorer and I am having the same issue.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Have you tried the Inbox endpoint to see if that makes a difference https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/mailFolders/Inbox/messages?$filter=from/emailaddress/address eq 'XXXXX@XXXX.com'

Comment: I would want you to test what @GlenScales suggested above and see if it helps. In the samelines, i tested my scenario with the query "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=from/emailAddress/address eq 'xxx@xxx.onmicrosoft.com'" and it worked for me(to get all emails from a specific address received by the signed-in user. In case if you're accessing other usermailbox then me wont work for you. You need to use /v1.0/users/user@domain.com/messages?$filter=from/emailaddress/address eq 'XXXXX@XXXX.com)

Comment: I will try that. It works for me 90% of the time. There are random queries that don't work when I can see emails from that user

Comment: @GlenScales I tried what you suggested and it worked the same way. Some addresses it find whiles others it does not

Comment: How old are the messages it doesn't find? and are the senders internal or external ? (internal senders will have an EX address for the sender but it shouldn't matter as the graph should handle it).  One thing you could try would be doing a Extended property query instead https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=singleValueExtendedProperties/any(ep:ep/id eq 'String 0x5D01' and ep/value eq 'gscales@blah.com') this targets the PidTagSenderSmtpAddress directly

Comment: I tried the below query and it said it is not valid. https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=eq 'String0x5D01' and ep/value eq 'xxx@xxx.com'

Comment: You check the 0x5D01 property in tools like EWSEditor or MFCMAPI for the given message and check its values...